# Java: GregorianCalendar Strange Output

Tags: java, date, java.util.calendar

I am new to Java and I am trying to get the yesterday date with the following code:

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2018,9,22);//<-Today
    gc.add(gc.DATE, -1);//<-Yesterday
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YYYY");
    System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(gc.getTime()));
```

The output I'm getting is:

> 325-XI-2018

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change from "DD-MMM-YYYY" to "dd-MMM-yyyy"

Comment: Search before posting. This has been covered many many many times already on Stack Overflow. And you are using terrible legacy classes.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DD-MMM-YYYY means :

- DD : Day in year
- MMM : Month in year (Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.)
- YYYY : Week year

If you want to display the date as 22-09-2018, use the format `dd-MM-yyyy`.

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Oh, I see now! DD was the one that got me lost with that 314.

Comment: Hey @3AKOBAH please consider upvoting and accepting the answer when it solved your issue.

Comment: The terrible `SimpleDateFormat` class was supplanted years ago by [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

The DateTimeFormatter class has lots a different ways of displaying the date and time. Check out the Oracle docs at:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html for more information and syntax

Comment: Some discussion and example code would improve this Answer. Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.